# My javascript setinterval loop multiplying by two instead of adding 1

Tags: javascript, game-loop

I'm trying to build a game loop, and it works fine with two loops, but when i try to add third one, it just multipling by two (my **"fires"** var) instead of adding "1". Can you please tell me where could be a problem?

```
function buyFire(){
    var fireCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,fires));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= fireCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        fires = fires + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        cookies = cookies - fireCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('fires').innerHTML = fires;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;


    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,fires));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('fireCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};


window.setInterval(function() {
    cookieClick(caves);
}, 900);  

window.setInterval(function() {
    cookieClick(cursors);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
    fireClick(fires);
}, 1200);
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/4rJGWVFG

Comment: because you are passing fires in the function which is the current value of fires. so fires+fires becomes 2*fires.

In setInterval fireClick(1) should be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give fires what is 1 and add it with a number in this case fire it self.

```js
var fires = 1;

function fireClick(number){
   fires = fires + number;
   console.log(fires);
};

setInterval(function(){ fireClick(fires); }, 1200);
```

So this is what you want to do:

```js
var fires = 1;

function fireClick(number){
    fires += number;
    console.log(fires);
};

setInterval(function(){ fireClick(1); }, 1200);
```

Instead of adding it like this: `fires = fires + number;`
You can write: `fires += number;`

The problem is the `setInterval()` function. You have duplicated setIntervals:

```js
var cookies = 0;
var fires = 0;
var cursors = 0;
var caves = 0;

document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("1.1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("3").style.visibility = "hidden";

function cookieClick(number) {
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

function fireClick(number) {
    fires += number;
    document.getElementById("fires").innerHTML = fires;
};

function buyCursor() {
    //works out the cost of this cursor
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors));
    //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    if (cookies >= cursorCost) {
        //increases number of cursors
        cursors = cursors + 1;
        //removes the cookies spent
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;
        //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;
        //updates the number of cookies for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "visible";
    };
    //works out the cost of the next cursor
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors));
    //updates the cursor cost for the user
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

function buyCave() {
    //works out the cost of this cursor
    var caveCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, caves));
    //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    if (cookies >= caveCost) {
        //increases number of cursors
        caves = caves + 1;
        //removes the cookies spent
        cookies = cookies - caveCost;
        //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('caves').innerHTML = caves;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("1.1").style.visibility = "visible";
        //makes update 1 visible
        document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "visible";
    };
    //works out the cost of the next cursor
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, caves));
    //updates the cursor cost for the user
    document.getElementById('caveCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

function fireUp() {
    if (cookies >= 1) {
        document.getElementById("3").style.visibility = "visible";
    };
};

function buyFire() {
    //works out the cost of this cursor
    var fireCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, fires));
    //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    if (cookies >= fireCost) {
        //increases number of cursors
        fires = fires + 1;
        //removes the cookies spent
        cookies = cookies - fireCost;
        //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('fires').innerHTML = fires;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
    };
    //works out the cost of the next cursor
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, fires));
    //updates the cursor cost for the user
    document.getElementById('fireCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

window.setInterval(function() {
    cookieClick(caves);
}, 900);

window.setInterval(function() {
    cookieClick(cursors);
}, 1000);

window.setInterval(function() {
    fireClick(1);
}, 1200);
```

```html
<div class=col-xs-3>       
  <span id="2">
    <center>
      Технологии
      <br />
      <button onclick="fireUp(1)">Приручение огня</button>
      <br />
    </center>
  </span>
</div>

<div class=col-xs-6>
  <center>
    <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Человек</button>
    <br /> Население: <span id="cookies">0</span>
    <br /> <button onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
    <br /> Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
    <br /> Cursor Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
    <br />
    <span id="1">
      <button onclick="buyCave()">Найти пещеру</button>
      <br /> Caves: <span id="caves">0</span>
      <br /> Cave Cost: <span id="caveCost">10</span>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span id="1.1">Люди замерзают, необходимы костры</span>
  </center>
</div>

<div class=col-xs-3>
  <span id="3">
    Постройки
    <br /><button onclick="fireClick(1)">Костер</button>
    <br />Костров: <span id="fires">0</span>
    <br /><button onclick="buyFire()">Разводитель костров</button>
    <br />
    <span id="fireCost">10</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: but then count down start as soon as i open the tab

Comment: it worked fine 

function cookieClick(number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

Comment: @Dmitry Gubanov I will look tomorrow at it for further explanation

Comment: thanks, that would be amazing, becouse i've been sitting on that for a whole day, and found nothing

Comment: @DmitryGubanov I will recommend you to create one `buyItem()` function. where you give parameters for the item you will buy. Now you have almoost the same functions `buyCursor()` and `buyCave()` are look a likes

Comment: so does that mean i cant have multiple interval functions? but i need thoose to keep track of different resources in a game, how can i do that?

Comment: @DmitryGubanov Yes you can but you had 2 the same. Look at my snippet and your code on the website. My snippet works how you want.

Comment: im sorry if i dont understand something, but in your snippet amount of fires is still multipling by two, instead of increasing by one
im sorry if im being annoyning, but i want to figure out what is wrong with my code, thanks for trying to reach to me

Comment: @DmitryGubanov I forgot to edit one part I think this is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This may have already by answered in the comments, but you specified your fireClick() as follows in the full source:

```
function fireClick(number){
    fires = fires + number;
    document.getElementById("fires").innerHTML = fires;
};
```

You probably meant to call it as fireClick(1), not fireClick(fires), which returns fires*2.

Comment: but if i call it fireClick(1) then fires will be counting as soon as i open the game, i dont want that to happen

Comment: @DmitryGubanov, is this only not working for fire? Did you forget to call it as window.setInterval(fx)? Shouldn't that set it to have a 1200ms delay?

Comment: yeah, its not working only for fire, becosuse for fire i just changed existing and working pieces of code, i have no idea what went wrong

Comment: In your full source, the other two are called as Window.setInterval(), fires says just setInterval(), could it be that?

Comment: nope, its just a typo, sorry for that, ill change it in pastebin